# Импорт файла в директорию выше, чем файл который импортирует его

Tags: php, html5

Доброго всем времени суток

```
if(copy($file, "img/".$new_name.".".$type)) {
    echo "импорт произведен";
}
else {
    echo "Файл НЕ был загружен.";
}
```

Это часть конструкции отвечающая за импорт файла на хостинг. Как видно, файл копируется в директорию img, с нужным именем. Если img/ убрать - будет копироваться в директорию с файлом, который отвечает за импорт.

Как загрузить файл на хостинт, в директорию выше, чем файл который импортирует его?

Допустим есть

```
.../.../folder1/ttt/folder2/index.php // здесь файл (index.php) который я переписываю
.../.../folder1/yyy/ // yyy - это папка с картинками, сюда хочу импортировать
```

Прошу совета, как подобное реализовать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

. - текущая директория
.. - родительская директория

т.е. пишешь вместо "img/" - "../нужная папка" или "../../нужная папка" и т.п.

Comment: До меня не сразу дошла глубина ответа, но когда я понял меня просто передёрнуло от счастья, что решение нашлось! Спасибо **nMike**